# Print output until key pressed

Tags: java, inputstream, user-input, keyboard-events

This seems like a simple problem, but I can't seem to solve it. I need to print output (from a variable) to the console, until the user presses any key. The printing is done in a while loop as such:

```
int i;
while((i=input.read())!=-1){
  System.out.print((char)i);
}
input.close();
```

The problem is that the input stream never reaches it's end, only waits for more characters to come in, thus blocking any more code from executing. It will be quite obvious to the user when to stop the output, so I am fine with giving that responsibility to the user. It doesn't matter how the user tells the application to stop, as long as it is quick, (eg pressing space, enter, or any other specific key is fine).

Thanks in advance,
vikarjramun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution I came up with was threading the console input. The thread updates a variable accessable by the printing code so you can check it before each print statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class RunUntilKeyPressed {
    static AtomicBoolean hasUserPressedKey = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println(scan.next());
            hasUserPressedKey.set(true);
            scan.close();
        });
        t.start();

        while(!hasUserPressedKey.get()) {
           System.out.println(hasUserPressedKey);
        }
    }
}
```

This code will run until the user presses Any Key (except space) and Enter as that is when the `scan.next()` method gets input.

Comment: This code might not work correctly unless you delcare hasUserPressedKey  as volatile or use AtomicBoolean instead of plain boolean

Comment: @vikarjramun If this solved your problem, please mark it as correct for others :)